# Pull a single line out of a matrix equation in sympy

Tags: python, sympy

In sympy, I have defined the equation `smile` as follows:

```
y = sp.MatrixSymbol('y', 2, 1)
x = sp.MatrixSymbol('x', 3, 1)
A = sp.Matrix([[ 1, 2, 3],[4, 3, 2]])
b = sp.Matrix([45, 56])

smile = sp.Eq(y, A*x + b)
smile
```

yields

```
Out[9]:
    ⎡1  2  3⎤     ⎡45⎤
y = ⎢       ⎥⋅x + ⎢  ⎥
    ⎣4  3  2⎦     ⎣56⎦
```

If I want to see the equation for `y[0]`, which is the first element of `y`, I can do this:

```
sp.Eq(smile.lhs[0], smile.rhs[0])
```

yielding

```
y₀₀ = x₀₀ + 2⋅x₁₀ + 3⋅x₂₀ + 45
```

But for the task at hand, I know only the *name* of the element, not the *number* of the row I am looking for. Is there a way to way to pull out just one line of the matrix equation given the name of the variable?

I'm imagining something like `smile[y[0]]` or `sp.solve(smile, y[0])`.

Comment: `np.where([y[0]==i for i in y])[0][0]` yields the correct index, but I hope someone can find more elegant solution than this.

Comment: What do you mean by the *name* of the element?

Comment: When you create a matrix in sympy using `MatrixSymbol`, its elements are callable using `y[0]`, `y[2,3]` and the like. I would like to use these "names" to slice entire rows of the matrix equation.